# C# function error as cannot redirect to another page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

so I am still new to C# and I currently testing out my project regarding a search function when user key in what they want to find out in a the textbox and press enter and it will redirect them to my search page. However everytime i tried to type things in the search button and press enter what came out is
    `http://localhost:51182/Default.aspx`
to
    `http://localhost:51182/Default.aspx?ctl00%24search=(whatever I keyed)`.
As the search function is in the masterpage.aspx i cannot use asp:buttons or what.

This is my code in the masterpage.

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
      <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." runat="server">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="Button1" onserverclick="Button1_OnClick"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
         </form>
```

This is my c# code for masterpage.

```
protected void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //The code was commented out since the search name was not able to be recognized in my webform input id so i tried to deal with the response first.
  //String searchtext = search;
  //String Search = Server.MapPath("Website\\HTML\\SearchEngine.aspx");
   Response.Redirect("~/Website/HTML/SearchEngine.aspx?search=");
}
```

I mainly put the codes that I think that matters and if required the other part just say so. In addition to it if this is a duplicate to other question, I am sorry as I been trying it out on some other question answer for their fixes to this but i wasn't able to get my working then I submit this question.

Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: Do you have a Form[runat=server] wrapping the content of the child pages from the Master? Or in any other spot?

Comment: @Graham erm in some pages yes there is another form with runat="Server" therefore i cannot use the runat ="server" for my masterpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can't have nested forms, but that's not to say that you can't have multiple forms on the same page, they just can't overlap, and only one can be an ASP.NET Form[runat=server]. Just make sure the search form, which can be a vanilla HTML form, is placed in the master page outside of any Form[runat=server] and format the search form like so:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="/Website/HTML/SearchEngine.aspx">
      <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." />
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

Comment: the action="/Website/HTML/SearchEngine.aspx" works for me but does it means the C# function to link to my searchengine is not needed and i will be able to take the querystring still from the site? since it links to the correct page with 
?ctl00%24search=asd at the back

Comment: Yep, you don't need the button click event anymore at all. The HTML form accomplishes the goal of "redirecting" to the target page with the user's input as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">... </form>
```

In ASP.NET WebForm, you cannot use another form tag, since there is a main form tag with `runat="server"` already.

The easiest way to achieve is to use ***Panel***. When user types inside textbox and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, it will call `Button1_OnClick` event.

*For example,*

```
<asp:Panel ID="SearchPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="SearchLinkButton">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="SearchTextBox" CssClass="form-control"
        placeholder="Search..." />
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="SearchLinkButton" CssClass="btn btn-primary"
        OnClick="SearchLinkButton_Click">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> 
    </asp:LinkButton>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: i will give it a try. Like u said i cannot use another form tag since this is a master page for my rest of the page and cannot have 2 form tags with runat="server". Nope it did not work since I need form runat=server which i should not have in my masterpage

Comment: Correct. Basically, we cannot nest two form tags.